# Tiling Window Manager, Terminal Multiplexer, Text Editor, How Do You Mange Windows?

Tags: terminal, tabs, text-editors, window-manager

I have seen people running a **tiled window manager** (like dwm, awesome, Xmonad) handling a **tabbed terminal** running a **terminal multiplexer** (like tmux, screen) running a **text editor** that supports split panes.

3 layers of window management leads to a lot of flexibility, and possibly complexity (especially when trying to remember which layer you're at so you know what key-binding to use).

If you use 2 or more of these window management layers, how do you manage your windows? **Which features do you use and which features don't you use?** Please indicate your platform.

Comment: this should be a community wiki, this question can't be answered with a single, correct answer.

Comment: @akira the option to mark this post as community wiki is not present in the edit view

Answer (score 1):

Right now I'm using OSX Terminal with tmux running Vim. This means I have `CMD+Tab` to switch between applications + `CMD+}` to change tabs in Terminal + `CTRL+J, #` to change windows in tmux + `CTRL+J, j/k/h/l` to change panes in tmux, `t,j/k/h/l` to change tabs in Vim, and `CTRL+W, j/k/h/l` to change windows in Vim.

My gosh what a mess!

An alternative is to use OSX Terminal tabs and run MacVim, which has its own tabs. Then we only have `CMD+Tab` to change applications, `CMD+}` to change tabs, and `CTRL+W, j/k/h/l` to change windows in Vim.